# Are there any unlockable characters and how to unlock them?

Tags: street-fighter-x-tekken

I'm playing the PC version of Street Fighter X Tekken, and I'm curious to know if the unlockables differ from the console version.

Comment: As a sidenote, questions that are basically, "See title" are almost universally bad questions.  Give them some love and flesh them out!  Context is important!

Comment: Noted.  But ,imo, even if the "everything-in-the-title" style isn't the sweetest one, it's still a pretty efficient one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no unlockable characters. All characters that are available in the game by default are playable from the outset.

[There is a paid DLC pack available](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/07/07/street-fighter-x-tekken-dlc-adds-12-new-characters-july-31/) that adds 12 additional characters, but you cannot play those characters at all without buying said DLC.